# Best Practice Jenkins, Angular and Spring

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I currently have a docker-compose file which runs nginx for Angular, spring and a database in seperate containers, but I am not happy with the way it is deployed.

So I looked into Jenkins to figure out how to solve this problem, but I can't quite understand how that setup should look like.

I am trying to figure out what the best practices in this situation would be:

1. Do I push changes to the dev branch of git which triggers jenkins to build, test and deploy the project?
2. Should jenkins automatically push changes to the main branch after succesful testing?
3. When should jenkins run the tests? Before deploying a docker container or inside the docker container? Or both?
4. Should the Angular project run in a seperate Container or inside spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I push changes to the dev branch of git which triggers jenkins to build, test and deploy the project?

Yes, absolutely.  That's what your CI system is there for.  (Possibly not "deploy", but it depends on what you have set up for a deployment environment.)

> Should jenkins automatically push changes to the main branch after succesful testing?

I wouldn't.  Code reviews, further manual testing, and just more time to think about what's on a feature branch could all result in more changes on a branch.  It's also valuable to be able to push a branch and have it tested before it's really ready to merge.

> When should jenkins run the tests? Before deploying a docker container or inside the docker container? Or both?

Jenkins should run your unit tests before building an image (or maybe using the native [Docker pipeline support](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) to get an interpreter or runtime environment).  These should have no external dependencies and should be fairly independent of the specific runtime environment.

Jenkins should also run integration tests after building an image.  This could involve launching multiple containers together or otherwise deploying the thing that just got built.  The test driver doesn't specifically need to run in Docker.

You should not build test infrastructure into an image.  You definitely should not bind-mount code into a container (beyond what the Jenkins integration will do on its own).  Test the actual image you're running, and build the image you plan to run in production.

> Should the Angular project run in a separate Container or inside spring?

It should be compiled into static files and then either Spring or a reverse proxy layer can serve them.  Most setups that run Angular in a container run a dev server, and this isn't hardened for actual usage.  Since the contents of the application are fixed once an image is built, it's also a little wasteful to run a dev server just to serve this up.